# datagridview CurrentCell ColumnIndex no value after re-open the form

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview which display data from mysql. When i open the form by clicking the button the form will appear as normal it will load the datagridview and displayed well. So here i check every column for each row of datagridview to check the days between the assigned date with today datetime. So basically if the totaldays is 1 i will set the column with assigned color. So this worked for 1st time open the form after debugging. Then i tried to closed/closing the form and reopen the form by click the button, yes it will load the data, but the color for each column is not assigned.
So here is the code where the each column color is assigned.

```
Sub Highlight()

    Dim row As Integer = myNewForm.DataGridView1.Rows.Count
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim j As Integer = 0

    j = myNewForm.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex

    MsgBox(j)

    i = myNewForm.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    Dim Ids As String = ""
    Dim todaydates As Date = Date.Today

    Dim testDate As Date
    Dim daysBetween = ""

    MsgBox(j)
    For i = 0 To row - 1


        For j = 1 To 9

            Ids = myNewForm.DataGridView1.Item(j, i).Value.ToString

            If Ids <> "" Then

                testDate = Function_Class.getDateOut(Ids, FacID())

                daysBetween = (testDate - todaydates).TotalDays


                ' If myNewForm.DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value = "GHHL1" Then

                If Ids <> "" Then
                    If daysBetween = 0 Then
                        myNewForm.DataGridView1(j, i).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
                    ElseIf daysBetween = 1 Then
                        myNewForm.DataGridView1(j, i).Style.BackColor = Color.Pink
                    ElseIf daysBetween = 2 Then
                        myNewForm.DataGridView1(j, i).Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                    ElseIf daysBetween < 0 Then
                        myNewForm.DataGridView1(j, i).Style.BackColor = Color.Green
                    ElseIf daysBetween > 2 Then
                        myNewForm.DataGridView1(j, i).Style.BackColor = Color.White
                    End If


                ElseIf Ids = "" Then

                    myNewForm.DataGridView1(j, i).Style.BackColor = Color.White

                End If

            ElseIf Ids = "" Then

                myNewForm.DataGridView1(j, i).Style.BackColor = Color.White
            End If

        Next

    Next i

End Sub
```

So i will pointing where the problem is occur. Loot at this part `j = myNewForm.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex` i echo out the value for j at there. At first time i debug and open the form, the value j will pop out show value 0.. After that when i close the form and click the button to re-open the form, the Msgbox does not pop out.. 
I have look around to find the problem i didnt found any working here.

Comment: What EXACTLY is `myNewForm`?  My guess would be that it is not referring to the actual form instance you're looking at on the screen.

Comment: i called Sub Highlight() at the myNewForm. The datagridview is displayed at myNewForm form. Sub Highlight() is in Module not the the myNewForm

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Im using data binding complete event in the myNewForm form for the DataGridView1. Put the Sub procedure the the Highlight() in the data binding complete event. This worked